# iframe has a scroll, but doesnt have a scrollbar?

Tags: html, css

I have a scroll on my iframe, but the scrollbar won't display?
how come ?

this is my code :

```
<div id="wpr">

        <iframe id="my-iframe"  scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" src="http://kikar.changemakers.com/%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%96%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%91%D7%97%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%9A"   >

        </iframe>
    </div>
```

```css
#wpr{ 
    width: 953px;    
    height: 500px;    
    overflow: hidden;    
    position: relative; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    height: 1366px;
}
#my-iframe{
    position: absolute;    
    top: -179px;    
    left: -147px;    
    width: 1262px;    
    height: 1587px; 
}
```

Comment: What operating system and browser are you using?

Comment: I tried it on FF and Chrome, both wont display the iframe.  I use windows XP

Comment: CSS: `overflow:scroll`, `overflow-y:scroll`, `overflow-x:scroll`

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski it wont work ..

Comment: @thormayer [it's working...](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZUaa/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#wpr{ width    : 953px;    height   : 500px;    overflow : hidden;    position : relative; margin: 0 auto; height:1366px;}
```

## my-iframe{

```
overflow-y:scroll;
overflow-x:hidden;    
position : absolute;    
top      : -179px;    
left     : -147px;    
width    : 1262px;    
height   : 1587px; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZZUaa/

kudus to Peter Szymkowski!